# How would a helper method for this UI code look like?

Tags: java, refactoring, wicket

I'd like to refactor some UI code.

I have a HTML form (here: written in a Java GUI called Wicket) where I put some links (anchor tags).
Instead of repeating the code over and over again, I want to create a new elegant helper method.

```
String type = "", id = ""; 
Form form, Service service;

form.add(new Widget("createLink", form) { // the same for read, update, delete
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public void onSubmit() {
        try {
            service.create(type, id);  // the same for service.read / update / delete
            info("Specific message for create, read, update, delete");
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            error(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e));
        }
    }
});
form.add(new Widget("readLink", form) {
    // ... service.read(...); info("... read ...");
});
form.add(new Widget("updateLink", form) {
    // ... service.update(...); info("... update ...");
});
```

As you've already guessed, I would like to have sth. like

```
form.add(createLink(htmlId, form, type, id, message, ?));
```

I'd like to avoid create an extra class for that. But Lambdas would be fine.

What would be the best approach?
And how is the pattern called?

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the strategy pattern because in your form add method you are passing different implementations Widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `?` you can use `java.util.function.Consumer`:

```
private void createLink(String htmlId, Form<?> form, String type, String id, String feedbackMessage, Runnable _onSubmit) {
    return new Widget(htmlId, form) {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Override
      public void onSubmit() {
        try {
          _onSubmit();
          info(feedbackMessage);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
          error(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e));
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
form.add(createLink("createLink", form, type, id, createMessage, () -> {
  service.create(type, id);
}));
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a nice solution. Why did you choose Runnable (instead of Consumer itself) in the example?

Comment: Because Consumer has a type (`<T>`) and you will have to use Void class for it in your case, and pass `null` when calling it.

Answer (score 1):

you can also take a look at [this utility class](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/master/wicketstuff-lambda-components/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/lambda/components/ComponentFactory.java) from WicketStuff that does something very similar with Ajax links.

Comment: Great. That's (ComponentFactory) even better in that particular context.